# net::ERR_ABORTED 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Tags: reactjs, http, path, header

my problem on on site when im using npm start :

```
Mail_Sende:25          GET http://localhost:3000/mateu52/Mail_Sender/static/js/bundle.js/ net::ERR_ABORTED 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)
localhost/:1          GET http://localhost:3000/mateu52/Mail_Sende/manifest.json/ 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

my json :

> "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/",   "scripts": {
> "start": "react-scripts --max-http-header-size=12000 start",
> "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"

i created setupProxy.js and was OK.
i tried change paramets in proxy->start,
and change in html file:

```
<!-- <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
```

day ago was ok i commited after serwerProxy.js created and cant loading app in React.
and my path to localhost wa change i dont know how. after where localhost:8000 after + app/name_app

Answer (score 0):

i create new app and copied my components and is running.